# Unity TCP/IP server accepts only local connections. Same code on same PC not on Unity works fine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tcp, tcpserver

When I run exactly same code on the same PC from inside of a Unity project and from a normal Visual Studio Project I get different results for a TCP/IP server.
Note that the ports are explicitly opened in the firewall.

The code is the following:

```
 IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Any;
 var s_server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
 s_server.Start();
 TcpClient socket = s_server.AcceptTcpClient();
```

That's it. Same code works in a stand-alone server located on the same PC (Windows 10 Home), but no connections are accepted when it's inside Unity. The funny part is that Unity does accept local connection on the same port.

I also tried to add some Unity specific code, like:

```
    Network.InitializeServer(16, port, false);
```

But it didn't help.
Any clue what is so special in Unity that it doesn't allow connections not from the localhost?

Thanks,
Vassili

Answer (score 0):

```
tcplistener.Server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
```

You probably need to set it as reusable in Unity.